# Can't access Database and models with Sinatra and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I am building a login form using Sinatra for static web pages and a custom model that stores data from the database. But the page is unable to recognise the model.

Here's the error I get:

[image]

My site.rb that sinatra uses:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

post '/login' do
  @result = AdminUser.select("*").where("email=? and password=?", params[:email], params[:password])
  render json: { status: 200, data: @result }
end
```

The AdminUser is a model that contains:

```
rails generate model AdminUser name:text picture:text email:text password:text
```

Checklist I tested:

- Database is connected and data can be read outside sinatra. I tested by creating an endpoint an claling it
- If the database code is commented out, the page is loaded successfully

What is the cause for this issue? How can I read the database and get the response using the current implementation?

Comment: Are you requiring some file that has AdminUser in it? You're not telling ruby what AdminUser is in your site.rb file. That's the problem you're facing. Why are you using Sinatra when building a rails app?

Comment: You might need to configure AR with Sinatra so it gets configured when the Sinatra app is running. That also would require to load modal files. But why mix both Rails and Sinatra in the first place?